# In this "captured variable cannot escape `FnMut`" error, what is the "returned reference"?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

What is going wrong here?

```
fn main() {
    // scope 1
    let mut i = 0u32;
    let _ = (0..2)
        .map(|_| {
            // scope 2
            // error : captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
            (0..2).map(|_| {
                // scope 3
                i += 1;
            })
        });
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3c000dd59b4d9e22fa69aacbef8adf2)

The full error is:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/main.rs:8:13
   |
3  |       let mut i = 0u32;
   |           ----- variable defined here
4  |       let _ = (0..2)
5  |           .map(|_| {
   |                  - inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
...
8  | /             (0..2).map(|_| {
9  | |                 // scope 3
10 | |                 i += 1;
   | |                 - variable captured here
11 | |             })
   | |______________^ returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

What is going on?

1. Why does adding `move` to parameter list of the second closure make the problem go away?
2. The full error message says that the second closure "returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body"? But the function returns unit. So what is rustc thinking? And what are the references? Is the `i` in scope 3 really a reference to an invisible reference in scope 2 to the `i` in scope 1?
3. Why does changing the second `map` to `for_each` make the problem go away?

Comment: *But the function returns unit* — it does not; [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) returns a `Map`. *`for_each` make the problem go away* — because it returns the unit type, which does not contain a reference.

Comment: I think that the main misunderstanding here is that _`map` does not consume the iterator_ instead it returns a new iterator that will produce transformed values _when consumed._ So it needs to keep track of the captured variables for when the new iterator will be consumed. OTOH `for_each` _does_ consume the iterator then and there, and so does not need to keep references around.

Comment: Also note that _if_ your code compiled, it would not modify `i` since you never consume the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a semicolon at the end of the inner `map()` makes the problem go away: the inner `map()` containing mutable reference to `i` is not returned to the outer `map()`, but you need to iterate through these `map()`s in order to alter `i`.

Using `move` in the inner `map()` gets rid of the reference to `i` by copying `i` into the closure so that the increment has no effect on the original `i`.

I don't really understand your original intent, but this seems to work:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut i = 0u32;
    let outer = (0..2).map(|_| {
        let inner = (0..2).map(|_| {
            i += 1;
        });
        for inner_elem in inner {
            println!("inner_elem={:?}", inner_elem);
        }
    });
    for outer_elem in outer {
        println!("outer_elem={:?}", outer_elem);
    }
    println!("i={:?}", i);
}
/*
inner_elem=()
inner_elem=()
outer_elem=()
inner_elem=()
inner_elem=()
outer_elem=()
i=4
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm asking the question mainly for my understanding, not to solve a problem. The original code was easily fixed by using `enumerate` rather than closing over a mutable variable binding and incrementing. But I had no idea what was going on.

Comment: You said that the `move` copies the `i`. Could you say more about this? I thought `move` moved (rather than copy) and that it's important to have **the same `i` ** (rather than a copy) so we can increment `i`.

Comment: @MaxHeiber `i` has type `u32` which is [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). Some types are marked with the `Copy` trait when they can be safely copied in a bitwise fashion (integers, reals...). Moving a binding to such a type is a simple bitwise copy and the original binding is left intact. Moving a binding to a more elaborated type (String, Vec...) is really different since the original binding is not usable anymore.

Comment: if `i` is copied, and I modify the copy, then the original `i` I copied from would not be modified. So it looks like something is really moved by the `move` closure.

Comment: @MaxHeiber in order clarify of my explanation on `Copy` (in the comment above): a move operation applied to a `Copy` type is nothing more than a simple bitwise-copy. So, yes, a `move` closure will simply copy `i` into the closure and leave the original `i` unchanged.